# Why do all negating words start with the letter N?

Tags: etymology, morphology

Maybe this question is stupid, but I came to wonder:

> Why do all negating words start with the letter *n*?

This is the case in all languages I know of.

Comment: I'm sure your idea is completely right, if you sample only words that start with *n*, in which case all negating words start with the letter *n*.  But in fact lots of negating words start with *[a-](http://www.etymonline.com/index.php?term=a-&allowed_in_frame=0)* (forms 2&3), *[ex-](http://www.etymonline.com/index.php?allowed_in_frame=0&search=ex-&searchmode=none), [in-](http://www.etymonline.com/index.php?term=in-&allowed_in_frame=0)* (form 1).

Comment: Not all words that imply negation start with N. That's true. [Negation](http://www.umich.edu/~jlawler/CELS-Negation.pdf) is a very big phenomenon. But there are an awful lot of words in an awful lot of languages that are important negatives and start with N. That's true, too, and the reason -- in Indo-European languages, anyway -- is that they -- as well as _un-, in-,_ and _a-_ -- all come from the same Proto-Indo-European root [***ne-**](http://web.archive.org/web/20080629221137/http://www.bartleby.com/61/roots/IE336.html).

Comment: Could you add that as an answer please?

Comment: To add to @JohnLawler’s comment (in case of link death, etc.), even the negating prefixes _a-_, _in-_, and _un-_ come from this _*ne-_. They represent the zero grade, _n̥_ (which in Greek and Indo-Iranian became _a_, in Italic developed a front vowel in front of it and went to _in_, and in Germanic developed a back vowel in front of it to become _un_). So they historically begin with an n, even if they don’t in the modern languages.

Comment: I offer Greek for the word of refusal, "No": όχι (óchi). I don't know whether this derived from the negative prefix α though (and that's probably out-of-scope for ELU.SE), but it appears on the face of it not to have much to do with *n*.

Comment: Confusingly, the Greek for ‘yes’ is ‘Ναί’.

Comment: Hebrew/Arabic negation words start with 'l'.

Comment: @AndrewLeach: όχι is (like its Ancient Greek ancestor, ουκί/ουχί (sorry, can't do polytonic on my phone)) an elliptical structure like _(ne) pas_ in French. It's lost quite a bit of steam, being originally from PIE _*ne h2oiu-kwid_ ‘not in any eternity’ or more loosely, ‘not on your life’. Interestingly, the first part, _*ne h2oiu_ ‘not in an eternity/not ever’ is what yields PGmc. _*ne ai(w)_, which yields Old English _ne ā_ > _nā_ > _na_, which gives Modern English ‘no’!

Comment: @Janus: Seem to me like your comments would make a nice answer to complement the existing ones. At least I'd upvote it if you did that.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

As John Lawler has indicated in a comment, most negating words in Indo-European languages derive ultimately from the root ***ne-**.

In non-IE languages, negative words take other forms, eg Hebrew לֺא (lo' = "not") or אין ('eyn' = "there isn't") or Turkish *yok* ("there isn't") or Georgian არ (ar = "not").

And even in IE languages, there are exceptions which have arisen in other ways, eg French *pas*, ("not", "none")  Welsh *ddim* (ditto),  Danish *ikke*, ("not").

Comment: Somewhat embarrassingly, I do not know the etymology of Welsh _ddim_, but the French and Danish words at least are in origin simple nouns that were used _together with_ the simple negator _ne_ (as is the case with ‘not’ in English, for that matter). French still retains the negation in formal language (where _pas_ is not the negating factor itself, but the negation-specifier, still seen as a pseudo-noun), though of course Danish has utterly lost it, as well as its original meaning.

Comment: Just realised that last sentence doesn't make sense. To clarify: Danish has completely lost the negation and the original meaning of the noun _ikke_ (which was ‘trifle, detail’, much like English ‘wight’, which underlies the negation ‘not’ < ‘naught’ < OE _nawiht_ < _*ne ā wiht_ ‘not ever a wight’).

Comment: The pattern is exactly the same for Welsh _ddim_. They're all instances of the Jespersen cycle. Indeed, English _not_ is also the result of that cycle, the  original negative element "ne" having been lost. (I suspect that this is true  of German _nicht_ as well, but I haven't researched it).

Comment: By the way, the apposite modern reflex of _wiht_ is _whit_, rather than _wight_. _Not a whit_ is still a recognisable phrase. _Wight_ does derive from _wiht_, but (until revived by imitators of Tolkien for a kind of ghoul), meant a person, not a thing.

Answer (score 2):

There is more to "a particle that negates or inverts the value of the stem of the word" than just the letter *n*.

The concept is dealt with in some detail on Wikipedia, mainly under:

**[Privative](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Privative)**
and 
**[Privative *a*](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Privative_a)**

> In Ancient Greek grammar, privative a (also known as privative alpha; in Latin, *α prīvātīvum*, in Greek, *α στερητικόν*) is the prefix *a-*  that expresses negation or absence (e.g., *a-theos*,  *a-typical*). It is derived from a Proto-Indo-European syllabic nasal **n̥-* , the zero ablaut grade of the negation **ne*, i.e. /n/ used as a vowel. For this reason, it appears as *an-* before vowels (e.g. *an-alphabetism*, *an-esthesia*, *an-archy*).[1](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Privative) It shares the same root with the Greek prefix *nē* or *ne*, in Greek *νη* or *νε*, that is also privative (e.g. *ne-penthe*).